# How can dynamic threading help in solve My performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

**.NET Framework used: 3.5** and 
**Visual Studio 2008**

I am having a method for executing certain updates on different databases.

Right Now i have a 'foreach loop' inside which the  function for executing the updates on the Database is called.The loop executes based on the number of databases.
There may be more than 700 databases in the client server.So the loop will execute 700 times which takes more than 10 hours which is a big performance issue.

One solution that we came across is dynamic thread creation.

For example:if  we have 100 databases then split it into 10 threads,Method with 1 to 10 databases will be handled by thread1,next the 10 to 20 database call will be handled by thread 2.....like wise 100 database updated using 10 threads.

Can any one please help me in make this work out.If you have any other suitable ideas please do share...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the worker thread pool like

```
public void DoWork()
{
    // queue in a loop
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(YourDatabaseWork));
}

private void YourDatabaseWork(Object state)
{
    // Insert code to perform a long task.
}
```

This way you can queue every single work you want to do (assuming you do not need too much memory to do it all at once). There is some number of worker threads available, all others will be put in a queue. So you should be able to simply "start" all your threads at once and each time one of the existing worker threads is done a new queued item is processed.

You can read more here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx

For how to use input parameters if needed you can read here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx

Comment: Thanks buddy.Let me see if i can make it out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best solved by asynchrony. If your update work is IO bound (and database update commands usually are ) your 700 threads will be just sitting there waiting for the database update to complete most of the time. The solution is to execute those updates asynchronously and then the thread pool will have more than enough threads for that.

You can kick off all updates at the same time and then just wait for the tasks to complete. If your updates are more complex and involve executing multiple queries, make each query execute asynchronously and `await` the result. Here is a simple example using .net 4.5:

```
public async Task UpdateDatabses(List<string> databses)
{
    List<Task> updateTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var db in databses)
    {
        updateTasks.Add(UpdateDatabase(db));
    }

    // asynchronously wait for all the tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(updateTasks);
}

public async Task UpdateDatabase(string databse)
{
    await /* Update the database */
}
```

**UPDATE**

For .NET 3.5 you need to install the *Task Parallel Librbary for .NET 3.5* package from Nuget. We require the `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.ConitnueWhenAll` extension methods but I wasn't able to find any versions for .NET 3.5. So i resorted to writing one myself:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a task that completes when all the passed tasks are completed
        /// </summary>        
        public static Task WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            var remainingTasks = tasks.ToList();
            int count = remainingTasks.Count();
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (var task in remainingTasks)
            {
                task.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var task1 in remainingTasks)
                        {
                            if (task1.IsFaulted)
                            {
                                exceptions.Add(task1.Exception);
                            }
                        }

                        if (exceptions.Any())
                        {
                            tcs.SetException(new AggregateException(exceptions));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tcs.SetResult(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return tcs.Task;
        }
}
```

Then you should be able to change your code to something like the following:

```
    public Task UpdateDatabses(List<string> databses)
    {
        List<Task> updateTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var db in databses)
        {
            updateTasks.Add(UpdateDatabase(db));
        }

        return Extensions.WhenAll(updateTasks);
    }

    public Task UpdateDatabase(string databse)
    {
        return null;  /* Update the database using a Task returninng asynchronous operation*/
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Ned Stoyanov.We are using .NET frame work 3.5.Can this solution be applied in .NET frame work 3.5

Comment: You can still use TPL for .net 3.5 but the code will have to be chaged as there is no support for `async-await`. I'll re-work it and post a solution.